# ANOVA analysis with R software

Tags: r, anova

I would like to perform the ANOVA analysis for the variable adjusted yield "adyield" (it is the mean adjusted yield for a sorghum variety over 3 years e.g., 2017, 2018 and 2020)  to see whether there is any statistical difference between the means values over years. According to my readings, the ANOVA is a suitable analysis for that. So, when I run the R code I had confusing results.
First: the result only 1 degree of freedom (df) or I think it should be normally 2 df once it is 3 years means.Second: the P-value is not significant for the "adyield" but I am having a significant intercept in the model. Here are the R codes, results and the dataset below for any help.*Note I should do the ANOVA for 5 variables as shown in the dataset.*

```
abcanova <- structure(list(year = c(2017, 2018, 2020), gprice = c(120, 125, 
125), adyield = c(1665, 1614, 2181), netincome = c(54375, 62310, 
122299), cbr = c(1.37, 1.45, 1.81), ic_share = c(41.29, 40.83, 
37.84)), row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = "data.frame")

abcanova %>%
  aov(formula = adyield ~ year, data =.) %>%
summary(abcanova)
            Df  Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)  
(Intercept)  1 9937200 9937200 310.842 0.0361 *
year         1  164813  164813   5.155 0.2641  
Residuals    1   31969   31969                 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Comment: You've fitted year as a continuous variable, not a factor. Hence a single degree of freedom.  A significant intercept and a non-sigificant coefficient for year means that your yields are non zero but do not differ between years.  If you need more detail, please migrate to stack exchange.

Comment: Many thanks for your comments which enlightened my understanding of the results. Please could you help me with the code to transform year into factor then I re-run and see. I going right to paste on stack exchange for further detail the issue. thank you.

Comment: `abcanova$year <- factor(abcanova$year)`, then rerun your model.

Comment: Many thank Sir but still have error message `> abcanova$year<-factor(abcanova$year)
> abcanova %>%
+   aov(formula = adyield ~ year, data =.) %>%
+   summary(abcanova)
Error in if (!intercept && pm > 0L) x <- x[-pm, ] : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
In addition: Warning message:
In Ops.factor(left) : ‘!’ not meaningful for factors`